# Unexplained exception with List<string>.Contains within a lambda for List<string>.Where

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Alright, so I am currently trying to find all strings in a list that don't exist in another list of strings. Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
var items = GetLiveItems(); // Returns List<string>
var currentItems = GetCurrentItems(); // Returns List<string>, Exception here

var rogueItems = items.Where(i => !currentItems.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

When I run the above code, I get a System.NullReferenceException on the second line. If I get rid of the 3rd line (items.Where...), the exception goes away. The two lists are rather large, first having 180k strings, second being 290k strings, but they are only 12 characters long each.

What could the issue be?

EDIT:

```
public static List<string> GetCurrentItems()
{
    var db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DB");
    var command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("getItems");

    var items = new List<string>();

    using (var reader = SafeSqlReader(db.ExecuteReader(command)))
    {
        while (reader.Read()) items.Add(reader.GetString("name"));
    }

    return items;
}
```

EDIT:

So using the below code:

```
var rogueItems = items.Except(currentItems).ToList();
```

worked. Can anyone explain why my previous method didn't? And the other suggested methods.

EDIT:

So, since I am having a hard time reproducing this in a project I can share with everyone to take a look, I want to provide this screen shot to prove I am not crazy.

[image: Unexplained Exception]

EDIT:

Here is a screen shot with the Except logic and you can see I successfully stepped over the line I got an exception before.

[image: No exception here]

Comment: What does the `GetCurrentItems()` method look like?

Comment: Let me ask it, to be clear: if you remove the 3rd line (`rogueItems`) the code works, if you run it like this, you get an exception on the 2nd line. Are you sure about it?

Comment: I'm sure GetCurrentItems is causing the `NullReferenceException`. What does it return? If it returned `IEnumerable`, it's probably not evaluating until the third line, and then it throws the exception.

Comment: @AndreCalil, that is right. I am sure. I've been messing with this for hours now.

Comment: I call "incorrect diagnostics" here. I'd be willing to bet money that there's something else going on, such as not running the code you actually *think* you're running. Are you *sure* `GetCurrentItems` returns a `List<string>` rather than `IEnumerable<string>` for example?

Comment: I will add the GetCurrentItems() method code

Comment: You need to close the Add method, you forgot one parenthesis )

Comment: @AlbertoLeón, oops, I was trying to format it pretty on here. I must have deleted it.

Comment: @ManuelMejia try change Contains for Exists(t=>t==i) Only for test purpose

Comment: Does `items.Except(currentItems).ToList` work?

Comment: And importantly, if you've failed to give the right code here, it makes it hard to trust the rest of what you've written. For example, perhaps you really *have* pasted `GetCurrentItems`, and that's not compiling, and that's the root of why you're seeing weird behaviour.

Comment: @JonSkeet, code is compiling, just edit error. I will try the suggestions for Exists and Except and come back with the results.

Comment: Using Exists still gets the exact same error. Using items.Except(currentItems).ToList() worked.

Comment: @JonSkeet We need your wisdom in explaining why `Except` changed anything. I can't think of a reason why.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Given that .NET generally obeys the laws of causality, I can't see any option other than *either* a compiler bug *or* a JIT/CLR bug *or* the OP has misdiagnosed things.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Is there anything that I could add to help determine the issue? I created a segregated project just to test the issue and that's the code above. The issue was also solved in my actual project. I could post some of that code if it would help.

Comment: @ManuelMejia what does SafeSqlReader look like?

Comment: @ManuelMejia: If you can create a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the *second* line throwing an exception based on the presence of the *third* line, that would be fabulous.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: I don't have access to its source code. Just a library we use at my work that takes care of doing int.MinValue and the like for SQL nulls. Nothing all that fancy.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Having a hard time reproducing with just random strings. I am posting a screenshot at the moment until I can reproduce it in a program I can fully share.

Comment: @ManuelMejia didn't think so. I was thinking maybe (although very unlikely) you had some custom lazy loading going on. I seriously have no idea what's going on in this example. But I'd be interested in debugging it too, if you end up putting that program together. I may even do it myself

Comment: @ManuelMejia: Is `Sears.Data.Services.ProductService` the name of a type, or is it a property access?

Comment: @JonSkeet: That would be the name of a type. Just holds a bunch of static methods for data retrieval.

Comment: @ManuelMejia: It definitely sounds to me like you're not debugging the code you think you are. If you make other changes to the code (before that line) do *they* show up? If you write some logging statement, put a breakpoint on it, and check the log before and after single-stepping, does it behave as you'd expect?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I tried out writing out to my log just before the line that gives an exception. I can successfully single-step and see it output to the log file.

Comment: The biggest difference between those two versions would be that the failing one lifts the variable to capture it for the lambda and the working one does not.  I would try a decompiler see if the capture class is being created and instantiated properly.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth: Yes, if the capture class weren't being instantiated, that would certainly explain a NullReferenceException where it looks impossible... but it would definitely be an odd compiler bug.

Comment: @JonSkeet: If I try to evaluate currentProductList in the immediate window during the exception, this is the result:
    currentProductList
    '' is null

Comment: @ManuelMejia: Well I'd expect that, as the assignment hasn't occurred yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `EXCEPT` Linq method - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Set-Operators-374f34fe rather than `WHERE !Contains`

Comment: I posed this as comment because I didn't have a good reason as to _why_ it could work but was curious if it would.  Do you have that reason?

Comment: @Austin - no I can't explain why it would work. I suggested it as it should work faster than enumerating the `currentItems` for every member of `items`. My suspicion would be that the lazy loading problem suggested by @Phillip Schmidt, whereby the IEnumerable isn't being populated until `GetEnumerator` is called, is causing some sort of issue with the `GetCurrentITems` method.

Comment: @Austin - my apologies for posting it as an answer. I honestly didn't see your comment with it in.

Comment: My head is exploding. All except does is enumerate through using the default `IEqualityComparer` to check for equality. I can't imagine how this would be functionally different from `Contains`...

Comment: @DuncanHowe:  No worries.  I wasn't calling you out or anything; I just couldn't come up with a supporting test on my box.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt:  Except returns the _set difference_ so this could yield different results if duplicates are involved.  On my machine, the runtime difference between the two methods is 228 seconds (228 secs for `Contains` vs 223 ms for `Except`) for lists of 180K & 290K strings.  The downside is that I can't get a NullReference...

Comment: @AustinSalonen: As long as there are no duplicates, Except should behave the same as the logic I was trying to implement with Contains, correct?

Comment: @ManuelMejia Well, that and `Except` will scale better for larger data sets because it puts the items into a `HashSet` which can determine if an item is in the collection much more effectively than a `List`.

Comment: @Servy: Would it makes sense to switch to have GetCurrentItems to return a HashSet instead of a string?

Comment: @ManuelMejia That depends on what you want to do with it next.

Comment: @Servy: Essentially I just need to do items - currentItems (items.Except(currentItems)) and then I will traverse through that list/hashset to using the strings it holds.

Comment: @ManuelMejia If you're only going to iterate the results then just return `IEnumerable`, which is what `Except` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a lazy loading issue. With linq, the query isn't actually run until you enumerate the result. So the problem probably lies in your SQL generation.

Comment: If it's really returning a `List<string>`, it won't be lazy though.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, true. Didn't look at that. Can't think of another way this would be possible, though.. Gonna keep this up here until he confirms. This *has* to be a lazy loading thing...right?

Comment: Or GetCurrentItems() is returning null instead of an empty list.  Doesn't find anything in the data store it is querying, and returns null instead of an empty list.  Then 3rd line tries .Contains on it and gets a null ref. exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet seems like it has to be. Or maaaybe there is another Linq query inside GetCurrentItems that returns IEnumerable. hmm

Comment: @Gromer then the exception would be on the 3rd line

Comment: @Gromer you and me both, my friend